# prove the inequality by induction for the folfowing expression

Tags: induction

1+1/2+1/3+1/4+.....+1/2^n>=1+n/2
I gOt stuck after 3rd step because I can't represent 3rd expression with the help of second one as there are other numbers between 1/2^k and 1/2^(K+1)

Comment: The inequality is false as stated. $1+1/2+1/4<1+\frac{2}{2}$

Comment: you have a strange series - it starts out as harmonic, but then the last term should be $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Yes, one of the two sides is wrong, the left side is convergent while the right side is not. But even if we have a harmonic series in the left, it would converge with rate $\log(n)$ while the right is linear.

Comment: This exercise is from Discrete Math Introduction (E. Sheinerman) I dont think that they would post wrong exercise

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that
$$S_n=1+{1\over2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^n}>1+{n\over2}.$$

Then:

$$
S_{n+1}=1+{1\over2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^n}+{1\over 2^n+1}+\cdots+{1\over 2^{n+1}}=S_n+{1\over 2^n+1}+{1\over 2^n+2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^{n+1}}.
$$
Apart from $S_n$, the rest of the right hand side is the sum of $2^n$ terms, each of them $\ge 1/2^{n+1}$. So we have:
$$
S_{n+1}>1+{n\over2}+2^n{1\over 2^{n+1}}=1+{n\over2}+{1\over2}=1+{n+1\over2}.
$$

Comment: how 1/(2^n +61/2^(n+1) is equal to 2^n*1/2^(n+1)? Arentino?

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood everything)